# Schedule Mic Recording

Tags: audio, microphone

Is there a way (automator maybe?) or program to make an iMac record the microphone input on a scheduled time (start and finish). I need it like some kind of security webcam but for audio

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://www.macworld.com/article/1158653/automator_voice_memo.html) explains something similar to what you are trying to do. I think that you can easily modify the workflow so it fits what you need starting from there.

Quote:

> Set up your workflow Launch Automator and in the New Template sheet
>   that appears, select Service and click Choose. Build a workflow that
>   contains these actions: New Audio Capture, Start Capture, and Stop
>   Capture (all under Movies). In the Start Capture action enable the
>   Wait For Capture To Complete option. In the Stop Capture action enable
>   the Close Movie After Stopping option. Configure the top of the window
>   to read Service Receives No Input in Any Application. Save your
>   workflow and give it an intuitive name such as Voice Memo.
>
> Voice memo window When you activate your workflow, the small Audio
>   Recording window will appear. If you now click Automator’s Run button,
>   QuickTime Player will launch, a new audio recording window will
>   appear, and your Mac will start recording from the sound input device
>   selected in the Sound system preference (from your iMac or MacBook’s
>   microphone, for example). When you’re finished recording, just press
>   the spacebar and your recording will be saved, the audio recording
>   window will close, and you’ll find your voice memo saved as Audio
>   Recording.mov in the Movies folder within your user folder.
>   (Subsequent recording will be called Audio Recording followed by a
>   number—Audio Recording 1.mov, for example.)